# Creating a list of strings in c not working?

Tags: c, string, memory

Im starting to learn c programming, and Im trying to split a string into a list of substrings. I created a structure for creating strings called String.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct dynamic_string {
    char* data;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
} String;
void free_string(String* s) { free(s->data); s->data = NULL; }
void print_string(String* s) { for (int i = 0; i < s->size; ++i) { printf("%c", s->data[i]); } printf("\n"); }
void clear_string(String* s) { s->size = 0; s->data[0] = '\0'; }

int string_init(String* s, size_t init_capacity) {
    s->data = malloc(init_capacity);
    if (!s->data) { return -1; };
    s->size = 0; s->capacity = init_capacity;
    return 0;
}

void add_char(String* s, char element) {
    size_t new_size = s->size + 1;
    if (new_size > s->capacity) { s->capacity = s->capacity << 1; s->data = realloc(s->data, s->capacity); }
    s->data[s->size] = element;
    s->size = new_size;
}

void add_charp(String* s, char* string) {
    size_t stringlen = strlen(string);
    size_t new_size = s->size + stringlen;
    if (new_size > s->capacity) { s->capacity = new_size << 1; s->data = realloc(s->data, s->capacity); }
    strcpy(s->data + s->size, string);
    s->size = new_size;
}

void add_string(String* s, String* string) {
    size_t stringlen = string->size;
    size_t new_size = s->size + stringlen;
    if (new_size > s->capacity) { s->capacity = new_size << 1; s->data = realloc(s->data, s->capacity); }
    strcpy(s->data + s->size, string->data);
    s->size = new_size;
}
```

Now this is not the problem. The problem occurs when I try to create a list of these strings. I also made a structure for doing this.

```
typedef struct dynamic_string_pointer {
    String* data;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
} StringVec;
void free_stringvec(StringVec* sv) { free(sv->data); sv->data = NULL; }
void print_stringvec(StringVec* sv) { for (int i = 0; i < sv->size; ++i) { print_string(&sv->data[i]); } }

int stringvec_init(StringVec* sv, size_t init_capacity) {
    sv->data = malloc(init_capacity * sizeof(String));
    if (!sv->data) { return -1; }
    sv->size = 0; sv->capacity = init_capacity;
    return 0;
}

void add_string_to_vec(StringVec* sv, String string) {
    size_t new_size = sv->size + 1;
    if (new_size > sv->capacity) { sv->capacity = sv->capacity << 1; sv->data = realloc(sv->data, sv->capacity * sizeof(String)); }
    sv->data[sv->size] = string;
    sv->size = new_size;
}
```

This structure does not seem to have problems and it works fine if you are adding different strings to it. The problem is when i build a string and add it to the list using the same variable.

For example:

```
void tokenize(char* text) {
    StringVec tokens; stringvec_init(&tokens, 32);
    String token; string_init(&token, 8);
    bool first_char = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); ++i) {
        if (isToken(text[i])) {
            if (!equals_charp(&token, "")) { add_string_to_vec(&tokens, token); }
            clear_string(&token); add_char(&token, text[i]); 
            add_string_to_vec(&tokens, token);
            clear_string(&token); first_char = false; continue; 
        }
        if (text[i] != ' ' && text[i] != '\t' && text[i] != '\n'){ add_char(&token, text[i]); first_char = true; } 
        else if (first_char) { add_char(&token, text[i]); }
    }
    print_stringvec(&tokens);

    free_string(&token);
    free_stringvec(&tokens);
}
```

Here I am trying to build the list of tokens by using the variable token and adding it to tokens. The problem seems to be that when token is passed to add_string_to_vec it always has the same address on the stack. This seems to be right because when I print tokens it just prints the last token over and over. So I tried replacing

`sv->data[sv->size] = string; with memcpy(sv->data + sv->size, &string, sizeof(String));`

thinking that this would copy the memory from string to sv->data so that when other tokens where added it would work. This seems to have the same problem. I usually work with c++ which has std::vector and std::string which makes this easy. I could just be stupid or maybe I just understand how memory works well enough, but I have not been able to figure out a way to get this to work.

Comment: `sv->data = malloc(init_capacity * sizeof(String));` strange ... Also `if (!equals_charp(&token, ""))` *very* strange ...

Comment: BTW, in `add_charp()`, if `new_size == s->capacity` the `strcpy()` will write the final `\0` to unowned memory.

Comment: You only call `string_init` once. That allocates one buffer that is then shared between all copies of the `token` string. Whenever you copy a `String` you will have to allocate a new buffer and copy the characters from the old `data`. (And then you will have *a lot* of trouble figuring out when to call `free`).

Comment: BTW: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); ++i) {...}` is a performance killer. (and static/inlined functions are your friend)

Comment: BTW2: If you usually do C++ you are not learning anything from trying to write C++ in C. And that's probably why you get downvoted by the C guys.

Answer (score 0):

I did what Bo Persson said, and made these functions. Now it works perfectly fine. (I changed the way the tokenize function works a little.)

```
String next_token(char* text, size_t size, int* start) {
    String token; string_init(&token, 4);

    char last_char = ' ';
    for (int i = *start; i < size; ++i) {
        if (last_char == ' ' && text[i] == ' ') { continue; }
        if (text[i] == '\t' || text[i] == '\n') { if (last_char != ' ') { add_char(&token, ' '); } continue;}
        if (isToken(text[i])) {
            *start = i;
            if (token.size == 0) { *start += 1; add_char(&token, text[i]); }
            return token;
        }
        add_char(&token, text[i]);
        last_char = text[i];
    }

    return token;
}

StringVec tokenize(char* text) {
    StringVec tokens; stringvec_init(&tokens, 32);

    size_t textlen = strlen(text);

    for (int i = 0; i < textlen;) {
        String token = next_token(text, textlen, &i);
        add_string_to_vec(&tokens, token);
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

I free token here.

```
void free_stringvec(StringVec* sv) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < sv->size; ++i) {
        free_string(&sv->data[i]); 
    } 
    free(sv->data); sv->data = NULL; 
}
```